# Can 's be used with et cetera?

Tags: possessives

In the line below is it correct to use the **'s** with et cetera ?

> I was reading headlines of New York Times, Wall Street Journal, Time **et cetera's** articles.

Comment: Yes, it can, but people uncomfortable with the Queen of England’s hat might not like it.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you can, but I have never seen such usage. To avoid the issue you could write:

> I was reading article headlines *from the* New York Times, Wall Street Journal, Time, et cetera (etc.).